# alternative to htmlspecialchars

Tags: php

We can use htmlspecialchars to stip out html tags.

```
$name = $_POST['inputbox1'];
$name = htmlspecialchars($name);
echo "Welcome".$name;
```

Is there another alternative?

Comment: It doesn't strip the tags, just encodes them. Just curious, why would you need an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to actually strip the tags, check out `strip_tags()`, but if you're looking for a semi-equivalent function, have a look at `htmlentities()`.

Answer (score 4):

PHP's [`strip_tags(..)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dedicated alternative function called [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

And remember, php.net is Your friend :)