# htmlspecialchars function not working in the xampp

Tags: php

I want to replace special characters in url address ,I use XAMPP and when I run this code for test :

```
   $new = htmlspecialchars("&", ENT_QUOTES);
    echo $new;
```

But I don't see any changes.

If I run my test app in the ideone.com , everything is working !
Why ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` has nothing to do with URLs, it handles HTML markup. Use the URL handling functions for URLs: http://php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Take a look at this (alternatives for htmlspecialchars): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574448/alternative-to-htmlspecialchars

Comment: thanks @arkascha , urlencode works perfectly!